# Pyomo: Saving subpotimal solutions from Gurobi (SolCount, X, Xn,SolutionNumber)

Tags: python, gurobi, pyomo

**I need to access and save the best suboptimal solution found by Gurobi within a specified time limit.**

Hello, everybody,

I've been using Pyomo with the solver gurobi to solve a certain model. The time to reach the optimum is very high, so I have specified a time limit for the solver by accessing the TimeLimit option:

```
optsolver = SolverFactory('gurobi',solver_io='python')
optsolver.options['TimeLimit'] = 30
results = optsolver.solve(instance1, tee=True)
```

After this I establish a conditional, so that if the solution ended in an optimal then this passes as an argument to a certain pyomo_postprocess function that organizes the values of the variables in a convenient way for my application.

Now, what I want is to make use of the attributes of gurobi SolCount, X, Xn, SolutionNumber **to save the best feasible solution reached before the time limit.**

This was my first attempt:

```
if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (
        results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):

    registro = open('registro'+data_name+'.txt', 'w+')
    registro.write('optimal and feasible\n')
    registro.close()
    pyomo_postprocess(instance1, results,data_name)

elif (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.aborted):
    registro = open('registro' + data_name + '.txt', 'w+')
    registro.write('TimeLimit\n')
    registro.write(str(results.solver.status))
    registro.close()
    pyomo_postprocess(instance1, results, data_name)
```

But:

WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with an 'aborted' status, but
    containing a solution.
ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: aborted

Could you tell me how to access these suboptimal Gurobi solutions in order to post-process them?
Thank you very much, greetings from Colombia!

Comment: If you use the Gurobi Python interface directly (without Pyomo), you can access the prior solutions as well as the solution pool.

Comment: @GregGlockner Thank you Greg, do you know if it is possible to do it using Pyomo? or do you definitely recommend me to go to Gurobi API?

Comment: I believe this issue is fixed in the current Pyomo version.
This is just based on my experience. I got the warning and Pyomo was able to return suboptimal solution.

Comment: This is not fixed with Pyomo 6.5 on Mac OS X. The suboptimal solutions from Gurobi are not loaded by Pyomo.